# Algebraic Long Division, find $3$ constants question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

When $x^4 - 2x^3 - 7x^2 + 7x + a$ is divided by $x^2 + 2x - 1$. the quotient is $x^2 + bx + 2$ and the remainder is $cx + 7$. Find the values of the constants $a, b$ and $c$.

I don't even know where to start...

Answers for reference = a=5, b=-4 and c=-1

Comment: Write it out & equate coefficients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is valid for all $x$:
$$
x^4 - 2x^3 - 7x^2 + 7x + a=(x^2 + 2x - 1)(x^2 + bx + 2)+(cx + 7)
$$
you can put:

$$x=0:\;\;\;\;\; a=-2+7\;\;\;\Longrightarrow \;\;\;a=5$$
$$x=1:\;\;\;\;\; 4=2(3+b)+c+7\;\;\;\Longrightarrow \;\;\;2b+c=-9$$
$$x=-1:\;\;\;\;\; -6=-2(3-b)+7-c\;\;\;\Longrightarrow \;\;\;2b-c=-7$$
So $b=-4$ and $c=-1$.

Comment: Daym that was simple, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

By definition of division we have:

$$
x^4 - 2x^3 - 7x^2 + 7x + a=(x^2 + 2x - 1)(x^2 + bx + 2)+(cx + 7)
$$

Calculate the RHS, and  equate the coefficients with the LHS.

Answer (score 0):

Or just do the division as suggested in the problem.  $x^4- 2x^3- 7x^2+ 7x+ a$ divided by $x^2+ 2x- 1$ is $x^2- 4x+ 2$ with remainder $3x+ a+ 4$.

You want $x^2+ bx+ 2$ to be $x^2- 4x+ 2$ and $cx+ 7$ to be $3x+ a+ 4$.

So you want b= -4, c= 3, a+ 4= 7.

Comment: Mark scheme says a=5,b=-4 and c=-1 so I'm still not quite sure how to do it, probs should of mentioned the answers above (sorry).